# Pentaho Spoon writes new txlog folder to old data-integration folder location

Tags: pentaho, kettle

Something in Pentaho data-integration saves the folder of the first location it was run.

This was a problem for me because I ran it for the first time in my downloads folder and then moved it to my Program Files folder.

Specifically the folder

> \data-integration\system\karaf\caches\spoon\data-1\txlog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the file

> data-integration\system\karaf\instances\instance.properties

and was able to change the line

> item.0.loc

to point to my new folder.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone whose problems are still not solved, you may be using a newer version of Kettle.

I had the same issue, and first followed Tyler's advice to find the file

> data-integration\system\karaf\instances\instance.properties

and change the `item.0.loc` property from the old path to the new.

However there were still odd goings on, and this didn't fully resolve the issue.

I ended up finding one of the cache bundles (in my case bundle 15) contained a `transaction.config` file buried deep in the filesystem which was still pointing to the old path:

> data-integration\system\karaf\caches\spoon\data-1\cache\bundle15\data\config\org\apache\aries\transaction.config

So I changed the `aries.transaction.howl.logFileDir` from the old path to the new, and it fixed the issue. Sneaky!

Comment: I resolved it by deleting the karaf caches folder at "data-integration\system\karaf\caches", but I guess this solved the same problem!